# Couldn't make a proper post request in iOS Objective C using UNIRest

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, delegates, http-post

I am trying to make a post request to a specific URL from an IOS app using a button and retrieve those posted parameters using 2nd button.

Here is what I am doing currently:

```
- (IBAction)firstButton:(id)sender {
    NSString *id = @"12345";
    NSDictionary* headers = @{@"accept": @"application/json"};
    session = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://xyz.io/sessions/%@/", id];
    NSDictionary* parameters = @{@"session_url": session};
    [[UNIRest post:^(UNISimpleRequest *request) {
        [request setUrl:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@devices/%@", BASE_URL, @"914-11e6-b775-02"]];
        [request setHeaders:headers];
        [request setParameters:parameters];
    }] asJsonAsync:^(UNIHTTPJsonResponse* response, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"post request submit error = %@", error);
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"post request success");
        }
    }
     ];}
```

and 2nd button to get the parameters looks like this:

```
    - (IBAction)secondButton:(id)sender{
       NSString *deviceId = @"914-11e6-b775-02";
        NSDictionary* headers = @{@"accept": @"application/json"};

        [[UNIRest get:^(UNISimpleRequest *request) {
            [request setUrl:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@devices/%@", BASE_URL, deviceId]];
            [request setHeaders:headers];
        }] asJsonAsync:^(UNIHTTPJsonResponse* response, NSError *error) {
            // This is the asyncronous callback block
            UNIJsonNode *body = response.body;

            if (error) {
                NSLog(@"error = %@", error);
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                NSLog(@"session = %@", body.JSONObject[@"session_url"]);
            }
         }
      ];}
```

Even though I am posting the "**session_url**" object from firstButton, when I am trying to get that from secondButton it always returns (null)

I am not sure why is it happening, any help would be appreciated.

P.S. In firstButton I am getting a "post request success" in the console log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I found the solution It was a very small mistake I was doing.

I changed the "post" request to "put" in firstButton and it worked for me.

Anyone looking for the difference between post and put request: 
https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html